# How to detect SQL injection attempt

Tags: java, sql-injection

I have a search field in my web application. the search function is safe from SQL injection perspective. However, I want to do some security logs each time someone attempts an SQL injection.

I have a Java input string on back-end, how can I detect when someone tries an injection? I tried some regex but without success.

Comment: What is the point? If your code is using prepared statement and parameters, and thus is safe, why would you spend time and energy to do this? Also, how would you distinguish genuine searches that just look like SQL injection, from actual SQL injection? You'd either create logs that no one will look at, or burn time "investigating" things, with no actual recourse (or even need) to address them. You waste time and money either way.

Comment: You could try to find SQL keywords as well as the SQL comment marker `--` and `;`

Comment: you should employ [web application firewall (waf)](https://owasp.org/www-community/Web_Application_Firewall) instead of baking some untested arcane code into your application logic directly. I mean, sql injection doesn't even need to be done using your search function.